# Aggregating different file CSV

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm beginner in C# and I don't know the API in details. 
I would like to write a one .csv that contains a *single day* from each of those files, and contains the data that was there in each file.

Comment: I have problems understanding your goal. You want to pick one csv file from specific date and after that ? Or you want something else ?

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?  Also, we could use some more detail about the problem.  Do you want the CSV files consolidated into one file, or just a list that groups the CSV files by date?

Comment: You want to search multiple CSV's for a specific day, then take each particular line matching that day, and output them into their own CSV?

Comment: for getting the files for the date you can do  'string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\",needed.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*.csv");'

Comment: @CodeCaster that's exactly what I wanted to do, to group all the files that have a matched date only and aggregate their cvs data in just one single day only. and keep doing that for all files. the problem is I have hours,mins,secs.

Comment: @CodeCaster could you elaborate more about your idea, because I'm newbie in C# and I have no idea how to make grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use plain loops in C#3.0, you could fill a `Dictionary` for example:

```
string dir = @"C:\DirectoryName";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
var dateFiles = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    if (fn.Length < "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss".Length)
        continue;
    string datePart = fn.Remove("yyyyMMdd".Length); // we need only date
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart, "yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        bool containsDate = dateFiles.ContainsKey(date);
        if (!containsDate) dateFiles.Add(date, new List<string>());
        dateFiles[date].Add(file);
    }
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, List<string>> dateFile in dateFiles)
    MergeFilesForDay(dir, dateFile.Key, dateFile.Value);
```

and here's a method that creates the new files:

```
static void MergeFilesForDay(string dir, DateTime date, List<string> files)
{ 
    string file = Path.Combine(dir, date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv");
    using(var stream = File.CreateText(file))
    {
        foreach(string fn in files)
            foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(fn))
                stream.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what MergesFilesForDay do ? Do you merge all the files into one file?  The thing is I want to merge all the files that have the same "day" into one and aggregate the data into one single CSV for all the files that have a single day

Comment: @moaz: first note that i've fixed the code, it's tested now. The method `MergeFilesForDay` creates one file per day with all the other files that belong to that day.

Comment: thanks but I wanted to merge them on the fly so that I have a single day. So that I can make a single .cvs and have all the days --> their CVS data, in just one cvs file, with the format day --> cvs data , day --> cvs data

Comment: @moaz: this code creates one file per day. So even if there are thousand files at one day it creates one huge file which contains all. But grouped per day(i thought that this was desired).

Comment: It may not matter in this case, but if the files are large I recommend that you use File.ReadLines(fn) rather than File.ReadAllLines(fn).  The reason is that ReadLines reads one line at a time but ReadAllLines reads all the lines at once.

Comment: @Casperah: the code has to run on C#3, that was one of the requirements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your help. I have another issue which is complicated. Now I merged the files by date. but each line has ID, x,y values. I want also to merge them by date and ID and sum x,y values from files that have similar ID :(. It's bit complicated for me. Would you please help me with that issue ?

Comment: @moaz: I would be glad to help. But you should post another question and show a simple example what you want to aggregate. Otherwise this question/answer gets off the subject. You can post a link here if you want, then i'll try to help. One hint: you can also use a dictionary to store and aggregate the values by ID. Btw, what is a _similar_ iD?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added another question. Thanks for your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376962/merging-and-sorting-data-in-cvs-by-date-and-id

Answer (score 2):

This will return all CSV filenames grouped by the first 8 characters of their filename, which is the date those files belong to.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetCsvFilesGroupedByDate(string csvDirectory)
{
    var csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(csvDirectory, "*.csv");

    var groupedByDate = csvFiles.GroupBy(s => Path.GetFileName(s).Substring(0, 8));

    return groupedByDate.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
}
```

You can then loop over the results:

```
var files = GetCsvFilesGroupedByDate(@"C:\CSV\");

foreach (var filesPerDate in files)
{
    // parse / concatenate CSV using filesPerDate.Key and filesPerDate.ToList()
}
```

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles is not available in .Net 3.5

Comment: You're right, ususally with C#-3.0 people use .NET3.5 in which the equivalent method is `Directory.GetFiles()`. See edit.