# Merging and Sorting data in CSV by date and ID

Tags: c#, csv

To continue the question: [Aggregating different file CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361974/aggregating-different-file-cvs/26362332?noredirect=1#comment41409134_26362332)

I have many files that have the format YYYYMMDD_HHmmss_goals.csv

Now I have a container that have one day and all list of files merged in one file.

The CSV has  multiples of different ID, X,Y. Now I want to merge them by single day with one ID and sum x,y of that ID and store them by single day. I also don't want them to be merged in one file, just on the fly, save the merged Single Day --> ID,x,y in one line of CVS format. its kinda like sorting them by one day and ID and sum their x,y but for that ID only.

**Update**:

```
public class XY_Values
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}


 public class ImageKey
    {
        public int mLocationId;
        public int mFormatId;
        public int mEditionId;

        public ImageKey(int LocationId, int FormatId, int EditionId)
        {
            mLocationId = LocationId;
            mFormatId = FormatId;
            mEditionId = EditionId;
        }

        public bool Equals(ImageKey x, ImageKey y)
        {
            return x.mLocationId == y.mLocationId && x.mFormatId == y.mFormatId && x.mEditionId == y.mEditionId;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ImageKey obj)
        {
            return obj.mLocationId ^ obj.mFormatId ^ obj.mEditionId;
        }

    }


    static void MergeFilesForDay(string dir, DateTime date, List<string> files)
{
    var idValues = new Dictionary<string, XY_Values>();
    foreach (string fn in files)
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fn))
        {
            string[] fields = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (fields.Length < 5) continue; // skip invalid data

            int LocationId, FormatID,EditionId;
            int x, y;
            bool LocationIdValid = int.TryParse(fields[0].Trim(), out x);
            bool FormatIDValid = int.TryParse(fields[1].Trim(), out y);
            bool EditionIdValid = int.TryParse(fields[2].Trim(), out x);
            bool xValid = int.TryParse(fields[3].Trim(), out x);
            bool yValid = int.TryParse(fields[4].Trim(), out y);


            if (xValid && yValid && LocationIdValid &&FormatIDValid && EditionIdValid)
            {
               ImageKey key = new ImageKey(LocationId, FormatID, EditionId);
                            bool knownId = enteries.ContainsKey(key);
                            if (!knownId)
                            {
                                enteries.Add(key, new XY_Values());
                            }

                            XY_Values entry = enteries[key];
                            entry.X += x;
                            entry.Y += y;

            }
        }
    }

    // don't know how would I combine them like to output cvs
    //LocationId, FormatID, EditionID, x,y   ... items 
    //Date:  
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. what have you tryed so far? can you show us some code

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I have posted my code

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti right now as you see I merge by date, now I have additional fields that I want to use, ID,x,y. I want also to merge the cvs lines to be just one ID and sum their x,y for matched ID, and all of that for single day. but I can't come up with proper data structure

Comment: @moaz: it's not clear, do you want to keep the logic of file generation by date or do you want to generate one file per date-ID combination? If the former, do you want to group by ID(without LINQ due to C#3) and sum all x and y values into one line?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes I want to group one file per date-ID and sum x,y of that ID, because there will be many IDs in each file. yes without LINQ due to c# 3. yes sum x,y in one line for one ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach  uses a `Dictionary<string, XY_Values>` to group by ID:

```
public class XY_Values
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

static void MergeFilesForDay(string dir, DateTime date, List<string> files)
{
    var idValues = new Dictionary<string, XY_Values>();
    foreach (string fn in files)
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fn))
        {
            string[] fields = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (fields.Length < 3) continue; // skip invalid data
            string id = fields[0].Trim();
            int x, y;
            bool xValid = int.TryParse(fields[1].Trim(), out x);
            bool yValid = int.TryParse(fields[2].Trim(), out y);
            if (xValid && yValid)
            {
                bool knownID = idValues.ContainsKey(id);
                if (!knownID) idValues.Add(id, new XY_Values());
                XY_Values values = idValues[id];
                values.X += x;
                values.Y += y;
            }
        }
    }

    string file = Path.Combine(dir, date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv");
    using (var stream = File.CreateText(file))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, XY_Values> idValue in idValues)
        {
            string line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", idValue.Key, idValue.Value.X, idValue.Value.Y);
            stream.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The method replaces the old [in my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361974/aggregating-different-file-csv/26362332#26362332).

Comment: How would you do it, if there is a unique ID and a only x is unique ? can a dictionary work here?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: i don't understand. What's the problem with a unique ID? You mean there is only a x-value without a y-value for one ID? You can change the logic above (`if (xValid && yValid)`) accordingly so that an invalid x/y is counted as 0.

Comment: Now It seems that I want to use a custom Key for the dictionary, like Dictionary<Entry,XY_Values>, where Entry has ID, and ResourceID are unique. very complicated now for me :S

Comment: I am on the way now, so i cannot show an example. But you have to override Equals and GetHashCode in Entry if you want to use it as key in a dictionary.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: i would help if i could but i'm very busy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class :

```
class ItemXY
{
    int X;
    int Y;    
}
```

then create a dictionnary :

```
Dictionary<int, ItemXY> dict = new Dictionary();
```

and foreach group of file, read all the files to populate dict :

```
string [] path_tab; //a tab of path, grouping all one day files

foreach (string path in path_tab)
{
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);

  while (!file.EndOfStream)
  {
    string [] tab;
    string s = file.ReadLine();
    tab = s.split(',');
    if (dict.Contains(tab[0]) //ID
    {
      ((ItemXY)dict[tab[0]]).X += tab[1];
      ((ItemXY)dict[tab[0]]).Y += tab[2];
    }
    else
    {
        ItemXY newItem = new ItemXY();
        newItem.X = tab[1];
        newItem.Y = tab[2];
        dict.Add(tab[0], newItem);
    }
  }
  file.Close();
}
```

After that, create your new CSV with the dict values.

Comment: yes, but now they are not merged by date, like the code above, should I add two separate data structures ?

Comment: before you have to group your files by date.

Comment: dataFiles[date].Add(file); You have that

Comment: if file is the path of your file and not the text in it, it will works